# Rejected edit had changes I didn't make

Tags: discussion, editing

[This edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5331) was rightly rejected.

But I only made the changes in the 3d paragraph (which someone else added separately), and didn't remove last part. Why would I?

Not sure what happened but maybe conflicting updates?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did see your edit and was not sure why you were deleting the reference to FAA website. I wanted to improve it by keeping the URL reference there but then had to pay attention to work.

I think you mistakenly deleted the sentence containing the URL link and then just saved the edit. When there was no reference to the URL at the bottom, the URL was removed too. That's the only plausible reason I can think of.

Another reason could be the following example:

- You are adding a URL reference in a question or answer.
- You clicked on the **Link** icon and pasted the URL in popup window.
- By accident, you clicked the **Link** button again.
- **WHOOOSH...** The URL reference is gone.

But in this case, the entire sentence should not be deleted.